# SSRS Must contain both values in results set

Tags: reporting-services, filter, ssrs-2008

Trying to run a report in SSRS to get tickets that have both of two values in the result set a Task Status of 'Completed' as well as 'Accepted' in the result set.  I want to remove any tickets that have all 'Accepted' as well as all 'Completed'.  I have tried using In and '=' as well as 'in' when using the filter but do not see the correct results when run.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming these two statuses are on different rows in the original table. The issue is that the operators you tried operate row-by-row and return true even if both conditions aren't met.

In your query, you could use a subquery to check for the presence of the second status. Or in the report, you could use a `Lookup` function to check for the second status.

Comment: I think is better to handle it at the query level using EXISTS. An alternative in SSRS to lookup is grouping by ticket and use a visibility condition=Not(Sum(Iif(Fields!Status="Accepted",1,0))>0 AND Sum(Iif(Fields!Status="Completed",1,0))>0 )